# Does Gboard remember what is said?

Tags: keyboard, privacy, gboard

I was using Gboard to write a message (with the microphone message). I said something rude I don't want it to save or repeat in predictions. Does Gboard save what is said anywhere, and if so how do I delete it?

I know some phrases you say to your phone do get stored in your Google Account, but I think this is mainly with "ok google".

By the way, on my phone it's called "Gboard" not Google Keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that it does not only save the audio,  it saves the activities you have done on your account in [Google activities](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity), so you can keep track of them, and also delete them, selecting one activity after the others.
It is like a history of your account

Comment: What does it show up as? There's nothing under "gboard" or "googleboard"

Comment: Try to say something to the keyboard and then go to that website... I did it like so and it appeared.

Comment: Try specifically this address: https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=29

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at the end of every mic message the keyboard make a toast appears that says

> Audio saved to *your account*

Comment: any idea how to remove it?

Comment: Didn't find any option that hinted about it, only a "share utilisation statistics" in the advanced menu, that I turned off just for the sake of it
I dont think there is a proper way to deactivate that function, sorry